# How to force a div to bottom of a wrapper div and set background color

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper `div` that contains two other `divs`, a `left-column` div and a `right-column` div. Currently the left column has a fixed min-height of `421px`. The problem becomes visible once content stretches out of the right column, effectively making the wrapper div larger than the initially specified height of `421px`. Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mertakus/0zx8vpk2/2/)

I want the left column to have a `min-height` of `421px` and stretch all the way to the bottom of the wrapper div and set a background color to it, even if it has no content in it. How can I do that?

```css
.wrapper{
  overflow: scroll;
  background: white;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  width: 298px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.left-column {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 421px;
  background-color: #144071;
  color: white;
}

.right-column {
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-column"> content content </div>
  <div class="right-column"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi officiis iste culpa, pariatur vel dolores aspernatur quo sint fugit. Eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi officiis iste culpa, pariatur vel dolores aspernatur quo sint fugit. Eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi officiis iste culpa, pariatur vel dolores aspernatur 
    <div style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <strong>Because the height of the right column is set to 100% and the left column to a fixed height of 421px, once content stretches out of the fixed height, the left column loses it's background color. How can I make it so that the left bkg color is stretched to the end, but has a minimal fixed height of 421px?</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I modified your fiddle using `display: flex` on the wrapper: https://jsfiddle.net/6gmL3z0n/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flexbox...

```css
.wrapper {
  background: white;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  width: 298px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.left-column {
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 421px;
  background-color: #144071;
  color: white;
}

.right-column {
  width: 70%;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-column"> content content </div>
  <div class="right-column"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi officiis iste culpa, pariatur vel dolores aspernatur quo sint fugit. Eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi officiis iste culpa, pariatur vel dolores aspernatur
    quo sint fugit. Eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi officiis iste culpa, pariatur vel dolores aspernatur
    <div style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <strong>Because the height of the right column is set to 100% and the left column to a fixed height of 421px, once content stretches out of the fixed height, the left column loses it's background color. How can I make it so that the left bkg color is stretched to the end, but has a minimal fixed height of 421px?</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your css like this:

https://codepen.io/shahry4r/pen/PowZOre

```
.wrapper{
  background: white;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  width: 298px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: auto; 
}

.left-column {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 421px;
  background-color: #144071;
  color: white;
}

.right-column {
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First, change the height of left column to padding-bottom. Second, change dynamic this padding-bottom for the height off the right column. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var rightHeight = $('right-column').offsetHeight;
    $('.left-column').css(padding - bottom: rightHeight);
})
```

Comment: No real need of using a) javascript, b) a javascript library.

Comment: Sure, it is not the best way to resolve this. Paulie show us the best form with Flexbox.